# Div tag borders

Tags: html, css, background-color

me and a mate are working on a html app similar that will look similar to the ipad twitter app.

http://www.iampersandi.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/04/photo3.png

I am wondering how they created the feint lines that seperate the dark grey user boxes.

I currently have this as a resizeable div, with each user having it's own div within that (eg Chris Purillo and Jeff Pulver would be in separate divs within the large resizeable div).

Is the feint line separating them just a clever truck using background colors with css3 or is there a better way to create this?

Answer (score 2):

You could try doing:

```
border-top:1px solid #46464f;
border-bottom:1px solid #282832;
```

Answer (score 0):

i would just use a background image that is 1px wide and 2px high with the two associated colors and set it to the top of the div

```
#div {
      background:url('border.jpg') repeat-x top
}
```

or even set it as a `border-image:` css property

http://www.css3.info/preview/border-image/